# Breadth-First-Search (BFS) in Python for Path Traversed and Shortest Path Taken

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I tried implementing a bread-first search algorithm a lot, but I just don't get it right. The start node is `S` and the goal node is `J`. I'm just not getting `J` at all.

[image]

This is the code that I'm using for printing the path being traversed, but I also need to find the shortest path:

```
graph = {
  'S' : ['A','B', 'C'],
  'A' : ['D'],
  'B' : ['E'],
  'C' : ['F', 'J'],
  'D' : ['G'],
  'E' : ['I', 'J'],
  'F' : ['S'],
  'J' : [],
  'G' : ['H'],
  'I' : [],
  'J' : [],
  'H' : ['D']
}

visited = [] # List for visited nodes.
queue = []     #Initialize a queue

def bfs(visited, graph, node): #function for BFS
  visited.append(node)
  queue.append(node)

  while queue:          # Creating loop to visit each node
    m = queue.pop(0) 
    print (m, end = " ") 

    for neighbour in graph[m]:
      if neighbour not in visited:
        visited.append(neighbour)
        queue.append(neighbour)

# Driver Code
print("Following is the Breadth-First Search")
bfs(visited, graph, 'S')    # function calling
```

Comment: I restored the previous version of your question: you shouldn't delete the code that your question was about: it is essential to your question, and the answer refers to it several times. Removing that code makes the answer refer to thin air.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it would be misleading since it's wrong so I just deleted it so that people see your code instead. I'm kind of new here so I don't know how things work

Comment: It is expected that in a question the code is wrong -- this is why it is a question. People will not look for answers in the original post, but in the answers below it. This is how Stack Overflow works ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to tell your BFS function what your target node is, so that the BFS traversal can stop as soon as that target node is encountered.

Some other comments:

- Your dict literal has a duplicate key `'J'` — you should remove it.
- `visited` and `queue` only serve a single BFS call, and should start from scratch each time a BFS search is launched. So these should not be global names, but be defined in the scope of the function only.
- You print the nodes as they are visited, but this does not represent a *path*. It represents a *level* order traversal of the graph. So don't print this. Instead have the function return the path (see next point).
- The list `visited` is used to avoid revisiting the same node again, but it doesn't give you any information about how we got to a certain node. You could transform `visited` into a dictionary. Then, when you mark a node as visited, mark it with the node where you came from. This way you can reconstruct a path once you have found the target node — you can walk backwards back to the starting node.
- You've defined `queue` as a list, but a list's `pop(0)` method call is not efficient. Instead use a `deque` and its `popleft()` method.

Here is your code with the above remarks taken into account.

```py
from collections import deque

graph = {
  'S' : ['A','B', 'C'],
  'A' : ['D'],
  'B' : ['E'],
  'C' : ['F', 'J'],
  'D' : ['G'],
  'E' : ['I', 'J'],
  'F' : ['S'],
  'G' : ['H'],
  'I' : [],
  'J' : [],
  'H' : ['D']
}

def bfs(graph, node, target):
    # These lists should not be global. At each call of BFS, they should reset
    visited = {}  # Use a dict so you can store where the visit came from
    queue = deque()    # Use a deque to not lose efficiency with pop(0)

    visited[node] = None
    queue.append(node)
    
    while queue:
        m = queue.popleft() 
        if m == target:  # Bingo!
            # Extract path from visited information
            path = []
            while m:
                path.append(m)
                m = visited[m]  # Walk back
            return path[::-1]  # Reverse it
        for neighbour in graph[m]:
            if neighbour not in visited:
                visited[neighbour] = m  # Remember where we came from
                queue.append(neighbour)
                
# Driver Code
print("Following is the Breadth-First Search")
print(bfs(graph, 'S', 'J'))
```

Output:

```
['S', 'C', 'J']
```

If you want to see which nodes get visited, then you have some options:

- Show when a node is dequeued from the queue:

  Change:

  ```
  m = queue.popleft()
  ```

  to:

  ```
  m = queue.popleft() 
  print (m, end = " ")
  ```

  or:
- Show when a node is enqueued to the queue:

  Change:

  ```
  queue.append(neighbour)
  ```

  to:

  ```
  queue.append(neighbour)
  print (neighbor, end = " ")
  ```

  and change:

  Change:

  ```
  queue.append(node)
  ```

  to:

  ```
  queue.append(node)
  print (node, end = " ")
  ```

The output is slightly different, and it depends on what you call "visited". The second one will output two more nodes that will never be popped from the queue.

To separate the output of the visits from the output of the path, just print a newline character with `print()`. So, in the driver code do:

```
path = bfs(graph, 'S', 'J'))
print()  # Extra print to start a new line
print(path)
```

Comment: The thing is that BFS does not visit nodes along a *path*. If you want to see in which order nodes are visited, then introduce that print again that you had in your original code. The order will be `S A B C D E F J` as it will stop at `J`. So three nodes will not be visited  (`G I H`).

Comment: This is the output when you print at the moment you *dequeue* nodes. You can have a different output if you output nodes when they are *enqueued*. That gives a slight different output, as then `G I` will also be output (they enter the queue, but never get off).

Comment: Like I wrote in my answer, you are not supposed to have `visited` as global variable, and should not pass it as argument. Secondly, you need to pass the target node as argument. Why don't you use the call of `bfs` I provided in my answer?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. I added a section to my answer. Make sure you start with the code I provided in the answer and not your own code.

Comment: That is indeed very basic stuff.  See addition at end of the answer.